# Java Script for clicking an element in all opened pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a JavaScript that click an element in all the opened pages in google chrome.

I used to use this script to click the element in the activated tab, but doesn't click the same element in the other tabs.

```
document.getElementById("ID of the Element").click()
```

Comment: Your JavaScript can only access the DOM on the page where it is loaded; you can't access the DOM on any other tabs that are open. That would be a terrible security hole!

Comment: The only things that can access multiple open pages are extensions. A work around for you however might be getting your pages to set and read cookies you can't have complex objects like an element but you could send data back and forth between pages that way (of course keep in mind that in most browsers only the active window (page) is actually having its scripts run  the other Windows only update when they are focused again)

Comment: thanks guys, I have just solve it right now by an extension from Chrome store, but there is one more thing if you could help me with it...I need JavaScript that click an element for specific interval and for 1 or 2 minutes. so is it possible ؟